# cartesian coordinate system with chart.js

Tags: chart.js, axes, coordinate-systems, cartesian-coordinates

I'm trying to create a cartesian coordinate system (i.e. for coordinate geometry) using chart.js. The documentation actually states "cartesian axes" but I'm not seeing any evidence that such a name is warranted. My chart is as follows:

```
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data: [{x:-3,y:5},{x:-2,y:0},{x:-1,y:-3},{x:0,y:-4},{x:1,y:-3},
            {x:2,y:0},{x:3,y:5}]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
              type: 'linear',
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1
          }
          }],yAxes: [{
              type: 'linear',
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1
          }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Problem right now is that the axes aren't passing through the origin (0,0). They are set off to the side just like any other ordinary chart. Does anyone know how to move the axes?

I tried setting the position of the axes but the only options are 'top', 'bottom', 'left' and 'right'. There is no 'middle', 'center', 'origin', etc. I also tried setting a label offset but this doesn't move in the right direction (x labels move in x direction, y labels move in y direction - I need the opposite) and this is only moving the labels anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) that offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. In the `beforeDraw` for example, you can compute and set the [`ticks.padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) of both axes in order to move the `ticks` to the desired position.

```
beforeDraw: chart => {
  var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
  var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];
  const scales = chart.chart.config.options.scales;
  scales.xAxes[0].ticks.padding = yAxis.top - yAxis.getPixelForValue(0) + 6;
  scales.yAxes[0].ticks.padding = xAxis.getPixelForValue(0) - xAxis.right + 6;
}
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  plugins:[{
    beforeDraw: chart => {
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];
      const scales = chart.chart.config.options.scales;
      scales.xAxes[0].ticks.padding = yAxis.top - yAxis.getPixelForValue(0) + 6;
      scales.yAxes[0].ticks.padding = xAxis.getPixelForValue(0) - xAxis.right + 6;
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Scatter Dataset',
      data: [{x:-3,y:5},{x:-2,y:0},{x:-1,y:-3},{x:0,y:-4},{x:1,y:-3},{x:2,y:0},{x:3,y:5}],
      borderColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -6,
          max: 6,
          stepSize: 1,
          callback: v => v == 0 ? '' : v
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false
        }        
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -6,
          max: 6,
          stepSize: 1,
          callback: v => v == 0 ? '' : v
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false
        } 
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```