# How to display an array in a cartesian plane using JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Given two simple arrays

```
X = [
  x1 => 1,
  x2 => 2,
];

Y = [
  y1 => 1,
  y2 => 2,
];
```

How can I display them in a cartesian plane using JavaScript on my website?

Comment: [One result](https://usefulangle.com/post/19/html5-canvas-tutorial-how-to-draw-graphical-coordinate-system-with-grids-and-axis) from a quick Google search. You'll get better answers if you show what you've tried and where you're having issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cartesian coordinate system with chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198240/cartesian-coordinate-system-with-chart-js)