# Possible to create quadrant chart with ChartJS, with the "origin" centered at a single point?

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to use ChartJS to plot a quadrant chart for a set of values and I'm wondering if there is a way to center the origin of the quadrants at some dynamic point when rendering the chart, as well as divide the chart into distinct quadrants with labels. Here is what my scatter plot looks like right now:

[Image of scatter plot with ChartJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMXfC.jpg).

The scatter chart was done with the following JavaScript:

```
var ctxScatter = document.getElementById('myChartScatter');
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctxScatter, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Data Point',
            backgroundColor: 'royalblue',
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHoverRadius: 10,
            data: [{x: 10.25, y: 89}, {x: 12.60, y: 69}, {x: 11.23, y: 78}, {x: 11.82, y: 71},
                   {x: 12.21, y: 85}, {x: 10.84, y: 75}, {x: 9.86, y: 86}, {x: 11.82, y: 62},
                   {x: 13.00, y: 79}, {x: 13.19, y: 74}, {x:12.02, y: 69}, {x: 14.76, y: 81},
                   {x: 13.39, y: 79}, {x: 9.66, y: 75}, {x:12.21, y: 78}, {x: 12.60, y: 77}]
        }, {
            label: '1st Quartile',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'seagreen',
            pointRadius: 7,
            pointHoverRadius: 14,
            data: [{x: 10.15, y: 85}]
        }, {
            label: 'Average',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            pointRadius: 7,
            pointHoverRadius: 14,
            data: [{x: 11.97, y: 77}]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                ticks: {            
                   callback: function(value){return "$" + value}
                }, 
                scaleLabel: {
                   display: true,
                   labelString: "Cost"
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {            
                   callback: function(value){return value + "%"}
                }, scaleLabel: {
                   display: true,
                   labelString: "Satisfaction"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

The scatter chart works great, but I need the yellow point to be at the dead-center as a fixed origin point for the four quadrants, as well as draw a vertical and horizontal line through this origin point to divide the chart into labeled quadrants, as shown below from my plot in Excel:

[Image of quadrant chart in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufjZM.jpg).

Is this possible?

Comment: This answer may help you to find a suitable solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63214514/2358409

Comment: I did come across this post when researching my solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't address the issue I am trying to solve. I don't need the data labels to be along the x-axis and y-axis, but I need to segment the chart into four quadrants from a specific point that is not (0,0), kind of acting as a new psuedo-origin, as shown in the Excel screenshot.

I'm also trying to force the chart to center around a specific point with the appropriate scaling (like with the yellow data point in the Excel screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

I was needing this same, here I share the model I made. I hope it helps you.

https://jsfiddle.net/aledc/1m89wju0/2/

HTML CODE:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="somatocarta" style="height:450px;width:500px;"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
var data = [
         {"x":0,"y":0},      // en el Centro
         {"x":-10,"y":30},   // cuadrante Superioro Alto Izquierdo
         {"x":15,"y":35},    // cuadrante Superior Alto Derecho
         {"x":45,"y":13},    // cuadrante Superior Medio Derecho
         {"x":52,"y":-13},   // cuadrante Inferior Medio Derecho
         {"x":25,"y":-33},   // cuadrante Inferior Bajo Derecho
         {"x":-25,"y":-33},  // cuadrante Inferior Bajo Izquierdo
         {"x":-42,"y":-14},  // cuadrante Inferior Medio Izquierdo   
         {"x":-42,"y":14},   // cuadrante Superior Medio Izquierdo

    ]

    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));


    Highcharts.chart('somatocarta', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundImage: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aledc7/Laravel/master/resources/somatocarta.png',
        renderTo: 'somatocarta',
            defaultSeriesType:'scatter',
            borderWidth:1,
            borderColor:'#ccc',
            marginLeft:90,
            marginRight:50,
    },

    title:{
            text:'Somatocarta'
        },
        legend:{
            enabled:false                                
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                shadow:false,
            }
        },
        xAxis:{
            title:{
                text:'X Axis Title'
            },
            min:-100,
            max:100,
            tickInterval:100,
            tickLength:0,
            minorTickLength:0,
            gridLineWidth:1,
            showLastLabel:true,
            showFirstLabel:false,
            lineColor:'#ccc',
            lineWidth:1                
        },
        yAxis:{
            title:{
                text:'Y Axis<br/>Title',
                rotation:0,
                margin:25,
            },
            min:-100,
            max:100,
            tickInterval:100,
            tickLength:3,
            minorTickLength:0,
            lineColor:'#ccc',
            lineWidth:1        
        },
        series: [{
            color:'#185aa9',
            data: data
        }]
});
```